# How to get all input elements in a form with HtmlAgilityPack without getting a null reference error

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack

Example HTML:

```
 <html><body>
     <form id="form1">
       <input name="foo1" value="bar1" />
       <!-- Other elements -->
     </form>
     <form id="form2">
       <input name="foo2" value="bar2" />
       <!-- Other elements -->
     </form>   
 </body></html>
```

Test code:

```
HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(@"D:\test.html");
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.GetElementbyId("form2").SelectNodes(".//input"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(node.Attributes["value"].Value);            
}
```

The statement `doc.GetElementbyId("form2").SelectNodes(".//input")` gives me a null reference.

Anything I did wrong? thanks.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();

doc.Load(@"D:\test.html");

HtmlNode secondForm = doc.GetElementbyId("form2");

foreach (HtmlNode node in secondForm.Elements("input"))
{
    HtmlAttribute valueAttribute = node.Attributes["value"];

    if (valueAttribute != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(valueAttribute.Value);
    }
}
```

By default HTML Agility Pack parses forms as empty node because they are allowed to overlap other HTML elements. The first line, (`HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");`) disables this behavior allowing you to get the input elements inside the second form.

**Update:**
Example of form elements overlap:

```
<table>
<form>
<!-- Other elements -->
</table>
</form>
```

The element begins inside a table but is closed outside the table element. This is allowed in the HTML specification and HTML Agility Pack has to deal with it.

Comment: Does this mean that, unless you use `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");`, it's not possible to parse children of `form` elements via HAP?

Comment: @Kevin, I don't have knowledge of any other alternative.

Comment: 5 years later - still a requirement, still the right answer. Also, still should be changed in the package itself...

Comment: Should be secondForm.SelectNodes(".//input")) instead of secondForm.Elements("input")), otherwise it doesn't get nested input elements.

Answer (score 0):

Just get them in array:

```
HtmlNodeCollection resultCollection = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@type='text']");
```