# Powershell 2.0 - Using HtmlAgilityPack to get children of FORM elements

Tags: html, powershell, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

Main problem stemmed from the fact that HtmlAgiltyPack won't get child nodes from a `<form>` element by default. See [How to get all input elements in a form with HtmlAgilityPack without getting a null reference error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2385840) for more information.

The problem is, that link shows how to fix the issue in C#, but I need to fix it in PowerShell. Any ideas?

---

I'll simplify my HTML

```html
<form method="POST" action="post.aspx" id="form">
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" name="test1" id="test1" value="1" />
    </div>
    <input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" value="12345" />
</form>
```

Now I see that when I select the `<form>` element, I don't get any children back, hence why I couldn't select the `<input>` elements.

```powershell
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\HtmlAgilityPack\HtmlAgilityPack.dll"
$HTMLDocument = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
$HTMLDocument.Load("C:\users\smithj\Desktop\test2.html")
$inputNodes=$HTMLDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form")
$inputNodes

# Output shortened to show important bits ...
ChildNodes           : {}
HasChildNodes        : False
```

You can see that `HasChildNodes` is equal to false.

From the C# link I provided, I somehow need to run `HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("form");` but I can't figure out what to type into PowerShell that would be equivalent.

Thanks again!

---

### EDIT

Thanks to *har07* for pointing me in the right direction. `[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode]::ElementsFlags.Remove("form")` was what I needed to run.

Note that I need to run that command *before* I load in the HTML.

```powershell
> Add-Type -Path ".\Net40\HtmlAgilityPack.dll"
> [HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode]::ElementsFlags.Remove("form")
True
>
> $HTMLDocument = New-Object HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument
> $HTMLDocument.Load(".\file.html")
> $HTMLDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//form")

# Output shortened to show important bits ...
ChildNodes           : {#text, div, #text, input...}
HasChildNodes        : True
OuterHtml            : <form method="POST" action="post.aspx" id="form">
                           <div>
                               <input type="hidden" name="test1" id="test1" value="1">
                           </div>
                           <input type="text" name="test2" id="test2" value="12345">
                       </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I'm not a user of PowerShell, but according to [this blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20160403194302/http://dpotter.net/technical/2008/01/calling-static-methods/), you may want to try something like this :

```
[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode.ElementsFlags]::Remove("form")
```

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful. Looks like `[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode]` doesn't have an `ElementsFlags` member though, so calling that doesn't work.

Comment: Ah, I wasn't looking at the static members of `[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode]`. Once I *did* look at the static members, I was able to see how to properly format the command. This was the eventual winner. Thanks again!

`[HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNode]::ElementsFlags.Remove("form")`